# Environment specific configuration property files in servlet application

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I want to implement code in servlet application in such manner that will have environment specific property files like spring boot application-dev.properties, application-stage.properties and so on.

So based on environment name configured, respective property file need to be refereed while running an application.

But i am not getting any way to do so. So guys can you suggest how i can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution should be to pass a JVM argument and read this argument in a [Servlet Filter](https://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial) for example to accomplish what you want.
The JVM argument could be called: "configurationFile" for example.

1. Pass a JVM argument : -DConfigurationFile=value
2. Read it in your code: value=System.getProperty("ConfigurationFile");
3. Do the processing you want

Best Regards,